# How to include LogicalThreadContext into logging output?

Tags: c#, log4net

From `LogicalThreadContext` documentation:

> The Logical Thread Context has a properties map and a stack. The
>   properties and stack can be included in the output of log messages.
>   The PatternLayout supports selecting and outputting these properties.

But `%x` pattern doesn't output anything from `LogicalThreadContext.Stacks["LDC"]`. And I can't find any pattern in [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) to output it.

How to include it to logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap your code with

```
using (log4net.ThreadContext.Stacks["stackName"].Push("Text you want to stack"))
{
    [your code]
}
```

And add that to your pattern

```
(%property{stackName})
```

**For Example** if you had multiple levels you could use the same name for the stack:

```
using (log4net.ThreadContext.Stacks["SN"].Push("level 1"))
{
    using (log4net.ThreadContext.Stacks["SN"].Push("level 2"))
    {
        log.Debug("Log Text");
    }
}
```

with a pattern like

```
(%property{SN}) [%message]
```

Would output something like

```
(level 1 level 2) [Log Text]
```

If you want more information you could take a look at [Jim Christopher's blog](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-6-Log-Event-Context.aspx)

Comment: `ThreadContext` is not what I want, will it work with `LogicalThreadContext`?